# GIT - How to switch Branch without carrying changes and viceversa

Tags: git

recently we moved from TFS to GIT so I am still learning how to use this amazing tool.

At the moment I am working in a very simple structure like the following one:

```
main -------------------------------------- 01 ----------
\                                           /
 dev ----------------------- 01 ---------- 02 ----------
  \                          /             /
   feat/login ------ 01 --- 02 --- 03 --- 04 --- 05 ---
```

- Developers work on `feature/something` and every tot hours they check-in and trigger a build with tests
- When the feature is stable they merge back into `dev` which will contains 1 or more checkins from `feature/something`
- When the whole feature is ready, they merge the feature from `dev` into `main`

The questions are the following:

- If I start to work from `feat/login`, if I do `git checkout dev` I don't get the latest code from `dev` but also my latest local file changed in `feat/login`. **How can I checkout `dev` without carry over the local changes not commited from my previous branch?**
- Assuming a developer made a mistake, how can I `rollback` to a previous check-in `01` in `dev` and push it so that the latest check-in `02` is not the last one anymore?

Comment: You either need to `stash` your changes before checking out a different branch, or `commit` them.

Comment: For the first question, are you asking how to remove those local changes when switching to dev? If you want to keep them you either have to commit them or stash them before switching, but if you simply want to delete them just do `git reset` after switching. Bear in mind that when you later switch back, they won't magically reappear, that's why you have to commit or stash before switching.

Comment: Super quick!
Guys write an answer so I can mark it as correct. `git reset` and `stash`, I didn't know :-)

Comment: For the second question, is the mistake so horrible that you want to remove the whole commit? That's history rewriting, not recommended if you're still learning git. If the mistake can be left in the repository, you just want to undo its effect, use `git revert SHA-of-commit` to create another commit that reverts the effect of the one you want to undo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) [Stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your changes, checkout to another branch, make some changes there and come back to your original branch and apply/pop your stash.

```
$ git stash
$ git checkout dev

# do something in you dev branch

$ git checkout feat/login
$ git stash apply
```

You can view your stash list using the command `$ git stash list`

2) It seems like you want to revert back the changes. I recommend you to not play with git history as a beginner. Anyways, if you do want to try it out here's a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit/4114122#4114122) how to do it. As [Lasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) said it's better to create another commit that reverts the effect of the one you want to undo.

Comment: perhaps it's worth noting that stash won't work with untracket files - if you have untracked files you don't want to "carry over", you have to commit them first, or stage and then stash

Comment: Quick tip: you can also stash untracked files using `git stash -u`

Answer (score 3):

Another feature that you may use, is `git worktree` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) which allows you to have working copies of multiple branches at the same time, so e.g. lets assume you are on master:

```
git worktree add -b dev ../dev origin/dev
git worktree add -b feat_login ../feat_login origin/feat/login
```

will give you 2 additional working copies in ../dev and ../feat_login that contain a working copy of the dev and feat_login branch.

I find this feature especially useful in projects were I have to switch between branches very often.